# How to refresh Vue after changes in DOM by an external script?

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js

I'm using [DHTMLX Gantt](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt) library which display nice Gantt Charts.

They do offer a [Vue Integration](https://dhtmlx.com/blog/use-dhtmlxgantt-vue-js-framework-demo/) which I can successfully use.

Once I've setup my gantt component, I can mostly interact with it.

However, I think that for rendering the Gantt chart, the library does some scripting (inserting divs etc...) not detected by Vue.

Is there anyway to tell Vue to "reload" the DOM once the DHTMLX gantt is over with rendering?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Frondor I'll do so. I'm trying to remember the name of the JS fiddle alternative that allows to run a full webapp

Comment: Do you mean codesandbox @SebastienD? https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: you can watch your data and call the method of the DHTMLX gantt instance(like refresh/reload method etc)